# Number Format 5.5 to 5.50 in PHP

Tags: php, date, number-formatting

The field value is : 5.5
But I want to show like : 5.50

I tried

```
number_format($_REQUEST['price'], 2, '.', '');
round($_REQUEST['price'],2);
```

but all showing 5.5

Comment: You need to store the result of number_format() in a variable, otherwise there's no point in calling it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you are rounding the number after you format it.

You need to round it first (or during the format). This should work:

```
number_format(round($_REQUEST['price'], 2), 2, '.', '');
```